# Java Wifi multiplayer

Tags: java, variables, wifi, multiplayer

I am making a wifi multiplayer game(like Minecraft wifi multiplayer), but I haven't found anything easy. I only want to send variables from one computer to the other.
A link would help enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not gaming expert in java, but found [something](https://code.google.com/p/lucu/) which may help you out. (Something concept of Apache Mina have been used.)